# Word for a phrase that is very commonly used to describe something

Tags: vocabulary, parts-of-speech

What is a word to describe a phrase such as "Anything can happen", which is often made in reference to baseball.  This is frequently said, but "platitude" and "cliche" aren't the right terms.  What type of phrase is this?

Comment: Why is *cliché* not the right term?

Comment: (And, besides, "anything can happen" refers to [Wednesday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9BWW6Mb7oA), not baseball.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of the many synonyms on offer, *[adage](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/adage)* is a good fit:

> A proverb or short statement expressing a general truth

Answer (score 3):

It can be described as a ***[set phrase](http://www.yourdictionary.com/set-phrase):***

> - (grammar) A common expression whose wording is not subject to variation.

(Yourdictionary.com)

Comment: Or a ***stock phrase***, which [is actually more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+set+phrase%2Ca+stock+phrase&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20set%20phrase%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20stock%20phrase%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3):

I would say that such phrases are ***hackneyed***, which the OED defines as:

> 7a. To make common by indiscriminate everyday usage; to render too
>   familiar, vulgar, trite, or commonplace. Also with out, about, upon.

But I also see them as *platitudes* and *clichés*.

Answer (score 3):

You might be referring to an **[idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom)**:

> "...a phrase or a fixed expression that has a figurative, or sometimes literal, meaning. [...] There are thousands of idioms, and they occur frequently in all languages."

Answer (score 2):

***Saying*** - A common phrase or expression, esp. a proverb, a maxim, an adage (OED).

Answer (score 2):

I'm rather fond of **colloquialism**

> a word or expression used in casual language by common people.

[yourdictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/colloquialism)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to call it ***pat phrase***.

> *"as we speak" is a pat phrase that means "at this very moment" or "right now."* [The Grammar Exchange](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/91510259)